# Where should I put file server in MERN application in Kubernetes?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

My application is running NodeJS, ReactJS and Mongodb in Kubernetes cluster.

And my app allows users to upload files to my server.

The below is my cluster structure:

```
NodeJS: 3 replicas
ReactJS: 3 replicas
Mongodb: 1 pod, service
```

Now I mounted Mongodb data to a persistent volume, and I can access it through NodeJS.

But how to handle upload files storage? Can I mount my NodeJS to the persistent volume?

I am not sure because it is running 3 replicas.

Or the simplest way is to create another new pod which is also running NodeJS to handle write/read for file storage?

I am using GKE.

Comment: Could you provide more details about your environment and scenario? Are you using `NFS`? I assume those pods will require to save and read from this PV?

Comment: you could use a `StatefulSet` and specify a `volumeClaimTemplates` as described in the kuberentes documentation here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#components

Comment: @ckaserer Thanks for reply! Do you mean I should use statefulset for nodejs instead of deployment? Also I would have 3 replicas for nodejs, and whether using Statefulset being more complicated?

Comment: Yes, a statefulset instead of a deployment for nodejs. It's pretty much the same as a deployment, so not that complicated. 2 major differences you can specify storage for each replica, the naming of your pods changes from a hash at the end to a numbering schema.

Comment: @ckaserer I just read some docs and tutorials about PVC and StatefulSet, but I still don't know how can I read/write the volume data from NodeJS. I guess is using NodeJS FS function to connect to the volume service ip to read/write that?